# Rendering button inside a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would one go about rendering a button with a click event inside of a list? I am not sure why I cannot render a button next to each dog in the list and add that dog to my cart array. I know I am missing something here because whenever I add a function to an `onClick` event I must get an error because my entire interface disappears.  Say I have a component:

```
var PetStore = React.createClass({
   getInitalState: function() {
      return ({
       cart: []
    })
   },
  addToCart: function(dog) {
    this.setState({
    cart: this.state.cart.concat([dog])
   })
 },
  render: function() {
     return (
       <ul>
         {this.props.dogs.map(function(dog){
          return <li>Breed: {dog.breed}, age: {dog.age} 
         <button onClick={this.addToCart}>Buy</button></li>
         })}
       </ul>
      )

   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var DOGS = [{
  breed: 'Husky',
  age: 5
}, {
  breed: 'Pit bull',
  age: 2
}, {
  breed: 'Golden Retriever',
  age: 10
}, {
  breed: 'Black lab',
  age: 2
}]
var PetStore = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    dogs: React.PropTypes.array
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      cart: []
    })
  },
  addToCart: function(dog) {
    this.setState({
      cart: this.state.cart.concat([dog])
    })
  },
  render: function() {
console.log(this.props);
    var self = this;
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.dogs.map(function(dog, index){
          return (<li key={index}>Breed: {dog.breed}, age: {dog.age} <button onClick={self.addToCart.bind(self,dog)}>Buy</button></li>)
    })}
      </ul>
    )

  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<PetStore dogs={DOGS}/>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

Comment: Hmm. Didn't seem to work. Does it matter than I am passing in an array of objects?

Comment: it doesnot matter , you can pass array objects anything in props. Can you tell the exact issue u are facing? Is button still not visible?

Comment: Whenever I include the addToCart function to the button event, nothing at shows up on the page at all. The list of dogs disappears--everything. Here is a link to for testing: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/yJgqeQ

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: also corrected the spelling of getInitialState , u missed i :P